# dbt query to Snowflake resulting in an "invalid identifier" error for a column that exists

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt, dbt-utils

I've been pulling my hair out for several hours trying to understand what's going on, to no avail so far.

I've got this query on dbt:

```
{{
  config(
    materialized='incremental',
    unique_key='event_ID'
  )
}}

SELECT
    {{ dbt_utils.star(from=ref('staging_pg_ahoy_events'), relation_alias='events', prefix='event_') }},
    {{ dbt_utils.star(from=ref('staging_pg_ahoy_visits'), relation_alias='visits', prefix='visit_') }}
FROM
    {{ ref('staging_pg_ahoy_events') }} AS events
LEFT JOIN {{ ref('staging_pg_ahoy_visits') }} AS visits ON events.visit_id = visits.id

{% if is_incremental() %}
    WHERE "events"."event_ID" >= (SELECT max("events"."event_ID") FROM {{ this }})
{% endif %}
```

Along with this config:

```yaml
version: 2

models:
  - name: facts_ahoy_events
    columns:
      - name: event_ID
        quote: true
        tests:
          - unique
          - not_null
```

`dbt run -m facts_ahoy_events --full-refresh` runs successfully, however when I try an incremental backup by dropping the `--full-refresh` flag, the following error ensues:

```
10:35:51  1 of 1 START incremental model DBT_PCOISNE.facts_ahoy_events.................... [RUN]
10:35:52  1 of 1 ERROR creating incremental model DBT_PCOISNE.facts_ahoy_events........... [ERROR in 0.88s]
10:35:52  
10:35:52  Finished running 1 incremental model in 3.01s.
10:35:52  
10:35:52  Completed with 1 error and 0 warnings:
10:35:52  
10:35:52  Database Error in model facts_ahoy_events (models/marts/facts/facts_ahoy_events.sql)
10:35:52    000904 (42000): SQL compilation error: error line 41 at position 10
10:35:52    invalid identifier '"events"."event_ID"'
```

I've gotten used to the case-sensitive column names on Snowflake, but I can't for the life of me figure out what's going on, since the following query run directly on Snowflake, completes:

```sql
select "event_ID" from DBT_PCOISNE.FACTS_AHOY_EVENTS limit 10;
```

Whereas this one expectedly fails:

```sql
select event_ID from DBT_PCOISNE.FACTS_AHOY_EVENTS limit 10;
```

I think I've tried every combination of upper, lower, and mixed casing, each with and without quoting, but all my attempts have failed.

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Most probably your column **event_ID** was created using "" around it which means an identifier was used. Now, using it also requires "" as all column names are capitalized inside Snowflake unless using identifiers.
Solution is to either use "" around column name or rename it to lower case using an ALTER.

For DBT you can read more [here](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/project-configs/quoting)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look into! I'm confused though, doesn't the error message prove that that's what the query is doing? `invalid identifier '"events"."event_ID"'`

Comment: If you check in Snowflake UI History how does the query from DBT looks like? Does it have the "" around the column name?

Comment: Good call on checking the queries log ! I actually combed through the query again and finally got back to the original error, which was caused by the incremental "engine" that uppercased all the columns regardless of the original query and table. This actually has been a documented issue that's supposed to have been fixed in 2019: https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/issues/1847

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should use Snowflake UI to check whether your column name is upper or lower case, because in the Snowflake database, `id` and `ID` are different.

Secondly, you should surround your column in `.yml` testing like this:

```
"<column_name>"
```

For example (`.yml` file in folder contains models):

```yaml
version: 2

models:
  - name: CREDITS_DIM
    columns: 
      - name: '"ID"'
        tests:
          - unique
          - not_null
```

Thanks for guy upper. My comment is for full step-by-step solution.

Solution quoting in `dbt_project.yml` didn't work to me. I'll explore this and update later.

```
quoting:
    identifier: true
```